# unable to create pkcs11 signature token using dss

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a signature generator using pkcs11 token with a .dll file.

This is the first time I try to create an electronic signature. In preparation, I tried to create one using pkcs12SignatureToken with a certificate that I had created using Openssl and it worked fine, but I can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XAdESSignatureParameters Parametres= new XAdESSignatureParameters();

    Parametres.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.XAdES_BASELINE_B);

    Parametres.setSignaturePackaging(SignaturePackaging.ENVELOPED);

    Parametres.setDigestAlgorithm(DigestAlgorithm.SHA256);

    System.out.println(DigestAlgorithm.SHA1.getXmlId());

    String PIN="XXXXXXXXX";

    PasswordProtection PINER = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(PIN.toCharArray());

    //This is where the Exception leads me
    Pkcs11SignatureToken token=new Pkcs11SignatureToken("C:\\Windows\\System32\\tuntrust_pkcs11.dll",PINER);

    DSSPrivateKeyEntry privateKey = token.getKeys().get(0);

    CertificateToken cc=privateKey.getCertificate();

    Parametres.setSigningCertificate(cc);

    CommonCertificateVerifier CommonVerifier= new CommonCertificateVerifier(Boolean.TRUE);

    XAdESService service = new XAdESService(CommonVerifier);

    DSSDocument toSignDocument = new FileDocument("C:\\\\Users\\\\Administrateur\\\\Desktop\\\\TTN\\\\Nouveau dossier\\\\firsttEST.XML");

    dataToSign = service.getDataToSign(toSignDocument, Parametres);

    SignatureValue signatureValued = token.sign(dataToSign, Parametres.getDigestAlgorithm(), token.getKeys().get(0));

    DSSDocument signedDoc= service.signDocument(toSignDocument, Parametres, signatureValued);

    signedDoc.save("C:\\Users\\Administrateur\\Desktop\\TTN\\Nouveau dossier\\Generated_Electronic_Signature.xml");
}
```

I was expecting a Signed xml file. However, I got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" eu.europa.esig.dss.DSSException: Can't initialize Sun PKCS#11 security provider. Reason: Unable to instantiate PKCS11 (JDK < 9) 
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs11SignatureToken.getKeyStore(Pkcs11SignatureToken.java:330)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.token.AbstractKeyStoreTokenConnection.getKeys(AbstractKeyStoreTokenConnection.java:43)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:141)
Caused by: eu.europa.esig.dss.DSSException: Unable to instantiate PKCS11 (JDK < 9) 
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs11SignatureToken.getProviderJavaLowerThan9(Pkcs11SignatureToken.java:242)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs11SignatureToken.getProvider(Pkcs11SignatureToken.java:223)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs11SignatureToken.getKeyStore(Pkcs11SignatureToken.java:303)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(java.io.InputStream)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3354)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2156)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs11SignatureToken.getProviderJavaLowerThan9(Pkcs11SignatureToken.java:239)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Which java version are you on? It seems `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11` is hidden or unavailable on your classpath.

Comment: I am using jre1.8.0_221 and in netbeans 11 I am using jdk 12

Comment: I believe some sun.* packages are hidden away in JDK 12. Do you have this exception on JDK12 only by any chance?

Comment: When i try to use other JDK's from the Source/binary format in netbeans, nothing changes. And if it helps, i can import sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 too. But if they are actually hidden, is there a way to make them visible?